# How to read php code with sprintf

Tags: php

I am self-learning php and I want to ask if am I reading this part of code correctly?
`If` powers is not empty, than make `array` from `values`, 
also each `power` will act like `power_id`. But `$values[]` is same as `array_pust()` ?  And `sprintf('(%d, %d)'` will put decimal numbers to character_id and power?

```
 $character_id = mysql_insert_id($db);
  if(!empty($_POST['powers'])) { 
  $values = array();
  foreach ($_POST['powers'] as $power_id) {
  $values[] = sprintf('(%d, %d)', $character_id, $power_id);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost as you described. `array_push()` can add multiple values at once, whereas single square bracket notation pushes one value onto the end of the array.

`$_POST['powers']` contains an array of values, so the `foreach` loop will iterate through these elements, and it refers to each element as `$power_id` within the loop.

`$values = array()` isn't strictly neccesary in this example, however it does declare `$values` to be an empty array, so makes the code clearer to understand. If you omit this line, PHP will deduce you wish to initialise an array when you first assign a value to it inside your `foreach` loop.